# Celery tasks are registered and running fine locally -- switch to EC2 and Celery doesn't register them

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, celery

I'm running a Django project with Celery and MongoDB as my broker that works fine locally. I am not using `django-celery`.  The project is located in `../myapp/` which looks something like this:

```
myapp/
    <other folders>
    aws/
        tasks.py
    celeryconfig.py
    settings.py
```

In this case, I'm just running the prototypical `add()` Celery example in `aws/tasks.py`, which contains:

```
@task
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

When I run `celeryd --loglevel=INFO` on the command line, it registers the list of tasks fine, and displays

```
[Tasks]    
. aws.tasks.add
. (all other tasks in tasks.py)
```

So now here's the problem. Executing the below lines in the Python interpreter works fine on my local machine

```
>>> from aws.tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(7,7)
>>> result.get() 
14
```

But when I try starting up celery on EC2, no tasks are listed as registered, and the above lines fail and result in the error

```
Received unregistered task of type 'aws.tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.
```

Here is my `celeryconfig.py`:

```
BROKER_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/rawDatabase"


CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "rawDatabase"
}


CELERY_IMPORTS = ("aws.tasks")
```

My `settings.py` contains:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
     'aws',
     ...
)
```

And yes, my `PYTHONPATH` contains `../myapp/` so celeryconfig.py should be picked up.

Any idea what could be causing this? Why is celery on EC2 not registering the task?

Comment: when '[tasks]' are empty, are you starting the worker with -l info?

Comment: btw, celeryconfig.py is not used when you use django-celery ...

Comment: sorry, saw that you're not using django-celery now.  I guess you should try and add print statement in your tasks.py module to see if the worker imports it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was an error with my `PYTHONPATH` on EC2. The project that I am working on that has the tasks in it lives in `/www/sites/siteA`. I have another project that lives in `/www/sites/siteB`. Both folders have a folder called `aws/`.

However, my `PYTHONPATH` looked like this: `/www/sites/siteB:/www/sites/siteA`.

When I swapped the order, celeryd was able to pick up and register the tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Is the celeryconfig.py you pasted exactly identical on your local and EC2 instances? I ask because there's a syntactical mistake on you celery imports line. For a tuple with one element, a trailing comma is required or else things won't be as you expect. Should be:

`CELERY_IMPORTS = ("aws.tasks",)`

instead of

`CELERY_IMPORTS = ("aws.tasks")`

Comment: Hi mateo, thanks for taking the time to respond. I actually do have more than one element in the tuple, it reads ("aws.tasks", "aws.otherTasks"), so I don't think it's that.